# How to connect netbeans 12 to Access database/ SQL database

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans

I am relatively new to netbeans and can't figure out how to connect to my database on Access. I am using Netbeans 12 and my database as well as UCanAccess-5.0.0 are in my source folder

This is the coding I have to connect to the database:

```
public class DatabaseManager {

    Connection conn = null;

    public DatabaseManager() {
        String filename = "HomeAffairs.accdb";
        try {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

            if (filename.endsWith(".mdb") || filename.endsWith(".accdb")) {
                String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + filename;
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url); 
            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
            System.out.println("Connection successful");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to get connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Querys the database
    public ResultSet queryDatabase(String sql) throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        return stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    }

    //Updates the tables in the database
    public void updateDatabase(String sql) throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(sql);
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate it if you could help me out!

This is the error I receive:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at HomeAffairsPackage.ApplicantManager.(ApplicantManager.java:26)
at HomeAffairsPackage.LoginScreen.LoginButtonActionPerformed(LoginScreen.java:177)
at HomeAffairsPackage.LoginScreen$7.actionPerformed(LoginScreen.java:143)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2764)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: Please add the exception if you are facing ?

Comment: Please update the question with exception

Comment: Watch here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhuafZrlWq4&ab_channel=WebTechTalkies